# Is it possible to sleep in critical section without lockup?

Tags: drivers, spinlock

I am using fsl_elbc_nand [1] driver for my NAND device. This is a NAND IC connected to the LocalBus Controller (eLBC), part of SoC. I have also ethernet MAC (ASIX) connected to the same ELBC bus. The nand driver works as follows:

1. setups operation via MMIO
2. wait_event_timeout for an interrupt from elbc informing that the operation (read/write/whatever) has finished
3. process result

Problem is, during wait_event_timeout() (which can take up to 0.5s) ASIX *cannot* talk with eLBC. But it is in three ways:

1. interrupt, when incoming frames
2. start_xmit from softirq for outgoing frames
3. mdio from ethtool ioctl (i.e. link status every second)

I can disable particular irq, resolving first case. I can return NETDEV_TX_BUSY by start_xmit, so I will resolve second case. But I cannot find any way to resolve third case. I tried spinlocks, mutexes, but I've learnt, that spinlocks are prohibited, when sleeping.

Is there some way to achieve proper locking? Maybe I should replace wait_event_timeout() to something else?

[1] http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/mtd/nand/fsl_elbc_nand.c?v=3.10